# Interdependent class template and std::is_base_of specialization

Tags: c++

I am mildy confused by the following situation where I have a specialization enabled on `is_base_of`.

`is_base_of` requires the full definition of the type that is being checked to be available. However, the type that is being specialized is being used as a member of the type who's base is being checked - so both need to be defined before the other, and I cannot forward declare the inheritance relationship.

What is confusing is that if I instead tag the base and enable on this tag existing, it works. Surely for this to work, the inheritance relationship must be known at this point. so why doesn't `is_base_of` work without the full definition being available?

```
#define OPTION 2 // OPTION 2 : broken, OPTION 1 : works

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;


template <typename T,typename Enable=void>
struct child;

template <typename T>
struct base
{
    typedef T type; 

    #if OPTION ==1
    struct base_tag{};

    #endif

};


#if OPTION ==2
template <typename T>
struct child < T, typename std::enable_if < std::is_base_of< base<typename T::type>, T>::value>::type>
{

     const char* value = "specialization";
};
#else

template <typename T>
struct child < T, std::void_t<typename T::base_tag> >
{

     const char* value = "specialization";
};

#endif



template <typename T>
struct dervived : base<T>
{
        child<dervived> child_;
        typedef T type; 
};



int main() {


    std::cout << dervived<int>().child_.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/YPVfIA)

Comment: You should split your example in two because it's already hard to follow and having to read through the conditional block does not really helps.

Comment: I tend to agree with Holt. If you leave just the option 2, it will be more readable. The tag workaround is really irrelevant.

Comment: You can reduce option 2 to this: https://godbolt.org/g/Ncm6Ad, and option 1 to about the same length. `slimbody` is not relevant here, you just want to check that the specialization is picked for `fatbody`.

Comment: But the question is about the tag workaround - so not irrelevant. The fact that the tag workaround requires that the type being checked is inherited from a base that provides the tag. So doesn't that require the inhertance relationship to be known, therefor why does is_base_of require the full definition ahead of usage. but when inherited and using a tag, doesn't.

Comment: @AndyG: I think it is unrelated to `void_t` vs `enable_if_t`, but incomplete type support between `is_base_of` and `T::tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::is_base_of` requires complete type. which is not the case in

```
template <typename T>
struct derived : base<T>
{
        child<derived> child_; // derived<T> not yet complete here.
        typedef T type; 
};
```

For `T::base_tag`, IIRC (I think POI of `child<derived>` move from before `struct derived` to current location in the class), `T` doesn't need to be complete, and only visited part of it is visible.

So `derived::type` would not be visible. (but `derived::base::type` would be).